# Can i limit the number of concurrent connections to a specific endpoint in Flask

Tags: flask, concurrency, gunicorn

I have a flask route that i want to limit to only have one or two concurrent connections at a time due to resource limits. At the same time i have a heartbeat endpoint that i do not want affected from high loads. Currently if i send many requests to the endpoint i want to limit, heartbeat requests will not be responded to since the instance will be under too high load. What is the correct way of going about this problem? Should i perhaps register my heartbeat route differently, or try to limit the number of concurrent connections for the one endpoint only. I am currently running my flask server with gunicorn

Comment: Do you want it to return an error to the client or just keep the client hanging until the resource is available?

Comment: Ideally just return an error